# Load Time Weaving controlling configuration

Tags: aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I'm using AspectJ (based on Load Weaving Time) in order to trace the flow by logs in my project. I want to give the user the ability to switch it on and off based on his needs. 
Is there any way to control these configurations (LTW jars and plugins) by any custom configuration? Because currently, in my project, the LTW activation depends on jar existence, which is not a good approach...

(just if it matters, I'm not using SPRING and my current project is based on OSGI Framework)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do that... I put all the aspectJ bundles include annotations and all related to it in a different directory and at OSGI installer in my framework I enable them according to true/false configuration

false will enable all bundles beside the aspectj bundles (so code wont be weaved) and true will active all.